# How to group this python list?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following array:

```
[1 , 2]
[1 , 3]
[1 , 4]
[2 , 3]
[2 , 4]
[5 , 1]
```

I want to print an output like the following:

```
    "Items related to 1:"

        2, 3, 4, 5 *note this last one was on the first column and 1 in the second

    "Items related to 2:

        3, 4

    "Items related to 3:"
        1, 2

    "Items related to 4:"
        1, 2

    "Items related to 5:"
        1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

```
def print_related(xs):
    d = {}
    for (a, b) in xs:
        d.setdefault(a, set()).add(b)
        d.setdefault(b, set()).add(a)
    for k in d:
        print "Items related to %s:" % k
        print "  " + repr(d[k])
```

This prints the sample input as

```
Items related to 1:
  set([2, 3, 4, 5])
Items related to 2:
  set([1, 3, 4])
Items related to 3:
  set([1, 2])
Items related to 4:
  set([1, 2])
Items related to 5:
  set([1])
```

You can use your own function in place of `repr` to print the sets differently, use a different data structure if you care about repetitions etc.

As per raymonad's comment below, you can also use `defaultdict` to avoid the two `setdefault` calls. Making this change and adding a hacky way to print the desired representation of the groups of related items results in

```
import collections

def print_related(xs):
    d = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for (a, b) in xs:
        d[a].add(b)
        d[b].add(a)
    for k in d:
        print "Items related to %s:" % k
        print "  " + repr(d[k])[5:-2]
```

Which prints the groups as `2, 3, 4, 5` etc.

Comment: I would prefer `d = defaultdict(set)`, so you can get rid of the two `setdefault()` calls in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
L = [[1 , 2],
     [1 , 3],
     [1 , 4],
     [2 , 3],
     [2 , 4],
     [5 , 1]]

from collections import defaultdict

assoc = defaultdict(set)

for a, b in L:
    assoc[a].add(b)
    assoc[b].add(a)
for k, v in assoc.items():
    print(k, v)


1 {2, 3, 4, 5}
2 {1, 3, 4}
3 {1, 2}
4 {1, 2}
5 {1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a dictionary where the key is a value in your arrays, and the key's value is a list of related values.

So, in this case it would look like:

```
{1: [2, 3, 4, 5], 
 2: [1, 3, 4],   # You missed `1` but it is related to `2`
 3: [1, 2],
 4: [1, 2],
 5: [1]}
```

Now, this will be easy to generate assuming the "relations" are not redundant. You could do something like:

- Iterating through the lists:
- Iterating through the elements in a given list:
- If the current element is not in the dictionary as a key, add it as a key and add the other value as the key's value in an array
- If the current element is in the dictionary as a key, append the other element in the pair to the list

Again this works if you have no redundant relationships. If you do have redundant relationships, then a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) is probably what you want instead of a list as the keys' values.